# Numerical optimization of discrete lognormal likelihood

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization, lognormal-distribution, discrete-data

## Problem Template

I am trying to numerically optimize a log likelihood function of the form:

$$\displaystyle \mathcal{L}(\vec{x}) = 
-n\log\left(1-\mbox{erf}\left[ A(m-1) \right] \right) + 
\sum_{i=1}^n\log\left(\mbox{erf}\left[ A(x_i) \right]- \mbox{erf}\left[ A(x_i-1) \right] \right) $$

where $$A(x) = \frac{\log(x) - \mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma},$$ $x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_n$ and $m\ge1$ are fixed integers, and $\mu\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma>0$ are the optimization parameters.

## Attempt at a solution

I have tried several canned optimizers in python and the results are inconsistent across optimizers, which makes me think I need to be more clever. I know there are classes of likelihood functions that are convex or otherwise nicely behaved (like exponential family distributions). Does this function fall into any similar categories where there are good ways for handling it?

## Background on where the likelihood function comes from

I am trying to fit a log normal distribution to discrete data. Since the log normal distribution is continuous, I have redefined a discrete version by binning the continuous distribution as follows:

Let $f(x)$ and $F(x)$ be the density and distribution functions of a continuous log normal variable, where

$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma x}e^{-\frac{\left(\log x-\mu \right)^2}{2\sigma^2}}, \quad x>0$$

and
$$ F(x) = \frac{1}{2 }+\frac{1}{2 }\mbox{erf}\left[\frac{\left(\log x-\mu \right)}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right] $$

We define $g(x)$ and $G(x)$ to be the density and distribution functions of a discrete log normal variable, given by:

$$ g(x) = F(x+1)-F(x), \quad x\ge0 $$
and
$$ G(x) = \sum_{y=0}^{x}g(y) = F(x+1)-F(0) = F(x+1) . $$

I further generalize this to start the distribution at any minimum value: rather than starting at 1, the distribution starts at $x=m$, where $m$ is some integer. This pmf is obtained by re-normalizing the tail of $g(x)$ so that it sums to 1 on the interval $m$ to $\infty$:

$$\displaystyle h(x) = \frac{1}{\sum_{x=m}^{\infty}g(x)} g(x)
 = \frac{1}{1-\sum_{x=0}^{m-1}g(x)} g(x) = \frac{1}{1-F(m)} g(x)$$

Comment: Since there are simple closed-form solutions to the continuous version of this problem, why not use them as initial solutions to the discrete version?  Moreover (although it's a little more complicated) there are closed-form formulas for simultaneous bounds on the possible values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$, which you could impose as constraints in the solver.

Comment: The optimisation methods you're trying may give different answers due to non-convexity. True initializing one method with the solution given by the other, does it then continue to return a different solution?

Comment: @whuber Can you explain what you mean by "formulas for simultaneous bounds"?

Comment: The information you have limits the possible values of $(\mu,\sigma)$ to a definite region of the plane.  This is described more generally at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_box#P-boxes_from_calculation_results.